# Is there a way in which I can ignore touch events on Text in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I want to implement floating labels, for this I have a `Text` Component Above a `TextInput`. I want to ignore all the touch events on the `Text` so that the `TextInput` under it gets all the events. Is there a way I can do this ? In CSS we used to have `pointer-events: none`, I am not sure how to do this in React Native.

Comment: It would be helpful to show us what you have so far.

Comment: I am trying to build something like http://codepen.io/soulrider911/pen/ugnyl

Comment: If anyone is looking for the solution in **normal React** (*not React Native*), you can simply set the css to `pointer-events: none` for the element that you want the clicks to pass through.

Comment: If you are using @react-navigation/drawer and getting this error, The below link might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76329208/20972519

Answer (score 263):

In react-native, [pointerEvents](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#pointerevents) is a prop, not a style.

```
<View pointerEvents="none" />
```

Comment: seems to work if set this way   `<View pointerEvents={'none'} />`

Comment: In some cases, you may want the subviews to still be the target of touches so pointerEvents={'box-none'} would be the appropriate solution: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#pointerevents

Comment: Also since OP asked about `Text` specifically, it's important to note that the `Text` component does not have a `pointerEvents` prop at all. SO, you will need to wrap the Text in a View and set the view's `pointerEvents` prop to be none.

Answer (score 63):

Add `pointerEvents: 'none'` to the `Text` component. This allows touch events to go to the ancestors of the component, but not the component itself or its children.

React Native also supports `'box-none'`, which allows touch events to go to the ancestors and children of the component, and excludes only the component itself.

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get it to work on a `Text` component, but wrapping the `Text` in a `View` and putting the `pointerEvents="none"` prop there solved it.

Answer (score 34):

I had the same problem as Cryszon. On Android is seems like pointerEvents="none" doesn't work for Text components.

> Wrapping the Text in a View and putting the pointerEvents="none" prop there solved it.

Answer (score 8):

`pointerEvents` work only on `View` not on `Text` or `TouchableOpacity`.

Comment: so what would work on Text or TouchableOpacity?

Answer (score 1):

So here is something that works for me. I was also trying to create a custom input component with a floating label. The trick here is to change the zIndex based on when the text input is focused or not, assuming your input field has a transparent background.

On the animated style that changes the position of the floating label, you can add a zIndex style like this:

```
const style = {
    zIndex: animatedValue.current?.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [0, 1],
        extrapolate: "clamp",
    }),
}
```

Now the floating label should be under the TextInput when the TextInput is not focused and above it when it is focused.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an issue where even `'box-none'` doesn't allow touch events to go to the children, you could do something like this

```
let setPointerEvents = 'none';
...
<View pointerEvents={setPointerEvents}>
   ...
   <TouchableOpacity onPress= {()=>this.set(false)}/>

</View>
<TouchableOpacity onPress= {()=>this.set(true)}/>
...
set(bool){
    switch(bool){
      case true:
        setPointerEvents= 'auto'
        break;
      case false:
        setPointerEvents= 'none'
        break;
   }
}
```

Kind of a hack, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to override a react `<TextInput>` object with a custom modal for input for example, you can do this:

```
<TouchableOpacity
onPress={() => this.openSourceOptions()}
>
  <TextInput
  label={"InputBox"}
  editable={false}
  pointerEvents="none"
  value={somevalue}
  mode="outlined"
  />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

PointerEvents didn't work on my View for some reason. I wrapped the View with a Pressable without giving onPress function. This worked for me.