# How to fix pointer event error ? React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, pointer-events

I've been getting this error in mac M1 laptop , meanwhile it is fine with my other device
[image: pointerEvents err]

I've been stuck here and cant fix these error , please help
Also there is this error "Requiring module "node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer/src/views/modern/Drawer.tsx"
I don't even install drawer in other device and it is fine

Note also when I search globaly for  `<View pointerEvents='auto' ...>` // pointerEvents , there is no such thing , since I never added that too to my view

Comment: try searching your node_modules folder for `pointerEvents="auto"` some code related to pressable has pointerEvent

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly weird thing is there is no pointerEvents anywhere or I've searched pointer-events there is none in any file

Comment: not much of a fix but you can downgrade `@react-navigation/drawer` to `5.12.9` until we get this figured out

Answer (score 2):

i was facing the same issue , you can fix it in drawer version "6.1.4". please verify the version on yarn.lock

Comment: how do you download the spesific version? with what command ? my version is 6.5.7

Comment: this might be the answer if I know how to change the version to 6.1.4

Comment: it should be "6.1.4" not "^6.1.4".

Answer (score 1):

The error is correct - pointerEvents is not a valid style property. It's a prop of View. Don't add it to your styles, set it directly on the View:

```js
  <View pointerEvents='auto' ...>
```

[See the docs for more on how to use pointerEvents](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#pointerevents). Auto is the default and doesn't need to be specified.

Comment: The thing is there is no  <View pointerEvents='auto' ...> anywhere or when I searched global also there is no pointerEvents thing

Comment: any other suggestion please ?

Comment: What are you trying to put the style on?

Comment: there is no style i've been putting in that correlated with pointerEvents or pointer-event, thats the weird part @Abe

Comment: hy did you fixed this issue?

Comment: no I still cant fix it @SaifUbaid

Answer (score 1):

I commented the pointerEvents: 'auto' from the @react-navigation library on this path
./node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer/src/views/modern/Overlay.tsx
error went away. I have the latest version of lib installed.

Answer (score 1):

`@react-navigation/drawer` v6.5.7 still has same issue. I don't know which version is buggy. But for me, lowering down to v6.5.0 did the work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `@react-navigation/drawer` and getting this error, you can either update the `@react-navigation/drawer` version to the latest that is `7.0.0-alpha.1`, or you create a patch to remove the pointer event from the style.

Go to the below location and find **pressable** style and remove the `pointerEvents` And add the `pointerEvents` to the overlay `Animated.View`

```
location: /node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer/src/views/modern/Overlay.tsx
```